# INFEASIBILITY due to value limit overflow?

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools, cp-sat

I am using CP-SAT for a model. In the model I am using product of integers and the domain of target variable is to its maximum value:

```
target_prod = model.NewIntVar(1, 99999999999999999, 'target_prod')
```

I guess there are **17 digits** for the maximum domain on positive side. (please correct me if I am wrong here, I also tried putting 18 digits but did not work)

**So my question is**, does the solver returs `INFEASIBILITY` when the value of `target_prod` goes over its upper bound?

And, any other way to I can distribute the product over multiple variables so support scaling of my model?

What if I change the domain to `(-99999999999999999, 99999999999999999)`, does the solver support this?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Cp-sat does not return infeasible, but invalid when a potential overflow is detected.

In the case of product, we treat in and intmax as infinity. So it should work.

Comment: thanks. I scaled my problem and I got ` Unsat after presolving constraint 
 (warning, dump might be inconsistent) : int_prod {  }` . And the Status says INFEASIBLE. So I am not sure.